# jQuery Slide to left right on a spitted Page

Tags: jquery, css

I want to split a HTML Page by 50%. If the left side is clicked than it should slide up to 90%. The same is for the right side.

I looked at some Sites but somehow could not get the Idea how to do it
http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions/

Comment: What part are you having issues with?

Comment: Well I will split the Page in two Parts, each with 50% and if this Part is clicked than it should move up to 90%. I don't know what I can use :(

Comment: you need to search for **Facebook slide menu effect**. it splits the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="left pane">
  </div>
  <div class="right pane">
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.main 
{
  width : 960px;
}

.pane
{
  width : 50%;
  height : 500px;
  float:left;
}

.pane.right
{
  float : right;
}
```

js

```
$(".pane").click(function()
{
  var ele = $(this);

  $(".pane").animate({
    width : 50%
  },
  3000,
  function()
  {
      ele.animate({
        width : 90%
     })    
  });
});
```

this is just an example to get to you started

if the right pane is growing out of the screen then you to animate the `margin-left` css property

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by having css classes with the varied widths you would want such as:

```
.half-page{
    width: 50%;
}

.expanded{
    width: 90%;
}
.collapsed{
    width: 10%;
}
```

Initially give each pane the half page class then add a click event to either pane when it is clicked to give the pane the expanded class and the other the collapsed class. (There are various ways to get this done)

This is not an extensive solution but is a push in the right direction for you to do research and learn on your own.